# REGEX: How to split string with space and double quote

Tags: regex

I have a input of string with spaces and double quotes as below:

Input :

```
18 17 16 "Arc 10 12 11 13" "Segment 10 23 33 32 12" 23 76 21
```

Expected Output:

```
18
17
16
Arc 10 12 11 13
Segment 10 23 33 32 12 
23
76
21
```

How can I do this using Regex? Thank you in advance

Comment: Thank you all for the answer ^_^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use next regexp[(see example)](http://regexr.com?35f54):

> ("[^"]+")|\S+

- ("[^"]+") - quoted sequence.
- \S+ - non whitespace sequence.

Probably order of groups is depend from regexp implementation. In the demo engine matching stared from left to right. Also do not forget escape special characters with double slash.

Answer (score 1):

`"(.+?)"|(\w+(?=\s|$))`

check [here](http://regex101.com/r/uM3wB4)