# Groovy null regex

Tags: regex, groovy

I would like to do the same task as this question but with groovy.

[REGEX: How to split string with space and double quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465099/regex-how-to-split-string-with-space-and-double-quote)

```
def sourceString = "18 17 16 \"Arc 10 12 11 13\" \"Segment 10 23 33 32 12\" 23 76 21"

def myMatches = sourceString.findAll(/("[^"]+")|\S+/) { match, item -> item }

println myMatches
```

This is the result

```
[null, null, null, "Arc 10 12 11 13", "Segment 10 23 33 32 12", null, null, null]
```

Comment: can you provide the desired result pls

Comment: Why not leverage something that parses text and is string delimiter aware, such as a CSV parser?

Comment: I would go with @tim_yates suggestion: do not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following, which uses [the Elvis operator](http://mrhaki.blogspot.ca/2009/08/groovy-goodness-elvis-operator.html):

```
def sourceString = '18 17 16 "Arc 10 12 11 13" "Segment 10 23 33 32 12" 23 76 21'

def regex = /"([^"]+)"|\S+/

def myMatches = sourceString.findAll(regex) { match, item -> 
    item ?: match 
}

assert 8 == myMatches.size()

assert 18 == myMatches[0] as int
assert 17 == myMatches[1] as int
assert 16 == myMatches[2] as int
assert "Arc 10 12 11 13" == myMatches[3]
assert "Segment 10 23 33 32 12" == myMatches[4]
assert 23 == myMatches[5] as int
assert 76 == myMatches[6] as int
assert 21 == myMatches[7] as int
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning the `match` instead of `item` gives nearly the expected result but the quotes remain. Don't know how to exclude them using regexp but removing the quotes from the result works:

```
def myMatches = sourceString.findAll(/"([^"]+)"|\S+/) { match, item -> match.replace('"', '') }
```